# DNN or IIS 401 Unauthorized error and some failed attempts to diagnose

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, http-status-code-401

I'm doing a first time install of DNN, following the tutorials at dotnetnuke.com, and I keep getting stuck.  I have Windows 8 so I'm having trouble getting answers from Google, so here's my problem...

When I launch the install wizard for dnn it looks like this:

### [image]

The stylesheet and images are clearly not loading, and the error console looks like this:

### [image]

So alright, maybe it's a permissions thing.  I check the properties of the folder tied to IIS and I see it's Read Only:

[image]

But the setting is stubborn and no matter how many times I uncheck the setting and apply to subfolders/files

[image]

It always goes back to saying it's Read Only.  I even tried forcing the change from the command line:

[image]

This morning I started to think maybe I'm chasing the wrong lead.  Maybe there's some IIS or DNN setting I've overlooked.  Unfortunately I'm out of my depth.  I'm trying to install DNN so I can learn it, so this is all new ground for me.  This is where you, the great people of Stack Overflow, come in.  Please halp!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check to see if you have STATIC content enabled in IIS?

To do this, go to start, run, type Add Remove Programs and then click on Turn Windows Features  on or off

Under Internet Information Services go to the World Wide Web Services section, Common HTTP Features and make sure Static Content is enabled.

**Update:**
Can you install this HOTFIX and see if that resolves the issue? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply!  I checked this and here's what I found: http://rodenbeek.com/preview/6.PNG

It looks like I already had that checked, but I don't know what a lot of these options are doing.  Maybe I have something checked I shouldn't?

Comment: I updated the answer with a hotfix link, can you try that? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Comment: There isn't a version for Windows 8.  This is my nightmare.  Thanks for the reply though,  man, please don't give up!

Comment: Can you expand the Security node under the WWW services in that screenshot you posted? I have Basic, Request Filtering and Windows Auth enabled on my local environment

Comment: I clicked on all of the Security settings shown in the above screenshot, restarted my computer, and the site still kicks out the 401 error.

Comment: Here's something that's probably diagnostically important; if I right-click and open one of the not-displaying images I get this [401.3 error page](http://rodenbeek.com/preview/8.PNG)

Answer (score 7):

You need to get the IIS Authentication -> Anonymous Authentication -> "Anonymous user identity" to match up to the file directory permissions. This is to allow the DNN code to execute within your file system. The recommended setting is to use "Application pool identity" to limit your IIS server/web site into other parts of your server environment.

[image]

From IIS management console or the wwwroot\yourDNNinstalllocation folder set the permissions to "IIS AppPool\ApplicationPoolName" to MODIFY. Note: the windows permission will require the **Location** to be "your-IIS-Server-or-PC-name" rather than any Domain location.

If you did want a domain role and integrated SQL Security on your database server, then you would need to

1. create a domain\user e.g. "yourDomain\dnn_yourCustomer" then
2. add that user to your SQL security for the DNN database AND
3. change your IIS anon identity to use the domain\user AND
4. set the permissions on the www folder to MODIFY to match your domain\user.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed it.  Maybe not "fixed it" so much as "didn't break it this time".  I deleted/uninstalled everything and went back to the first video.  The part I hadn't noticed before was when he says if you're using SQL Server Management Studio ***Express***, skip the setting up a database step.  So I did, and everything worked.

I did another step that I found when I Googled "IIS 401.3 unauthorized error".  It said to add the IUSR user to the security settings on the dnndev.me folder.  I'm not sure if this played any role in fixing things, but it didn't hurt nothin' neither.

Anyways, problem's fixed.  Thank you, Chris, for the replies.  I appreciate your help, and I look forward to diving into the rest of your tutorial videos at dnn.com

Comment: Glad you got it working! Sorry there was so much trouble with it

Comment: Would you mind doing a bit more troubleshooting? If you remove the IUSR account does the problem occur again? With IIS7/7.5, when you create a website, it creates an application pool and an identity for that pool. I don't know if IIS8 does the same or not, but you would add the security for "iis apppool\dnndev.me" with MODIFY permissions on the DNNDEV.me folder in the file system. I am wondering if that fixes the problem you are having.

Comment: Absolutely!  I took off the IUSR account and the site still worked.  I think the problem I was having had to do with ignoring your pleas to not set up the database if I was using SSMS Express.  So I had the App Pool tied to a database that was set to "COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS" instead of ".".  I assume, honestly I'm out of my depth with all of this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the game, but I also ran into this issues and tried to fix it using the answers here. I couldn't get it all to work after trying the above fixes, so I looked at the permissions on the default app in IIS. It had two users called `WEBMGR1\Users` and `WEBMGR1\IIS_IUSRS`. I added both of them and it worked.

Comment: I had this same problem like a week later and researched and found this answer and it fixed my problem and then I realized it was my answer. Amazing.